# How do transactions get to miners?

Tags: exchanges, transaction-propagation

How operations from exchange and other ways of transferring bitcoins goes into 'system' (mining people)?

Comment: @DaveC By my question I mean that - I'm transferring BTC from A to B account and how does that information goes into packets of 25 transactions and then to people who mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computers running the Bitcoin software pass transactions from one to the other to rapidly distribute new transactions throughout the network. Miners accumulate transactions from the network to put into blocks that they mine.

If you go to [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) you can see new unconfirmed transactions scroll by on the bottom left.